# How To Check a double value whether is Int or double

Tags: c#

Is That Any calculation or method allow me to check whether a double value is Int or Double in c# code

Example

```
Double NumberOne = 55.00 // Return False 
Double NumberTwo = 55.10 // Return True
```

Comment: Cant you cast it to int and compare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
 if (Math.Floor(number) == number) {
     // yay, an "int"
 }
```

Comment: `double.PositiveInfinity` and `double.NegativeInfinity` are also identified as integers with this code.

Answer (score 3):

```
    private bool IsDoubleNotAnInt(double num)
    {
        if ((num % 1) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Except that in his example, he returns `true` when it is **not** an int ;).

Comment: Now your method name is inaccurate :P.

Comment: I hate logical thinking. Updated again  :P

Answer (score 2):

You could check

```
n % 1 == 0
```

to determine this.

Comment: This should be marked as answer, it should handle special floats as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare it with value without fractional part:

```
Math.Floor(n) != n
```